# How to determine the eigen values of $A^tA$ where $x^tA A^tx=\alpha x^tx ~~~~ \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^m$ holds for some $\alpha$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> **Problem.** A be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $m$ with $n>m$. If for some 
>   nonzero real $\alpha$ we have 
>   $$x^tA A^tx=\alpha x^tx ~~~~ \forall x \in \Bbb{R}^m$$
>   then $A^tA$ has
>
> 1. exactly two distinct eigen values
> 2. $0$ as an eigen value with multiplicity $n-m$
> 3. $\alpha$ is a non zero eigen value.
> 4. exactly two non zero eigen values.

**My attempt.**

We know, $rank(A^tA)=rank(A)=m$. So, $Nullity(A^tA)=n-m>0$
So, $0$ is an eigen value of $A^tA$ with geometric multiplicity $n-m$. But $A^tA$ is symmetric so is diagonalizable i.e. $0$ is regular. Hence **$0$ is an eigen value of (algebraic) multiplicity $n-m$** i.e. **Option 2 is correct.** (without using the given equation)

Now we have to conclude about the rest. I think for this we have to use the given equation.

I start by checking for the non zero eigen values of  $A^tA$ (In fact, $A^tA$ should have $m$ non zero real eigen values)

Let $\lambda$ be a non zero eigen value of $A^tA$. Then there exists a **non-null** vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $A^tAv=\lambda v$. Now to use the given equation I think we need a vactor $x \in \Bbb{R}^m$. So, I try to choose $x=Av$ in that equation.....But I can't get any conclusion from there...!!

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**N.B**: This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821581/deduction-of-eigenvalues-of-the-matrix-a-which-satisfies-xt-a-at-x-alpha). But I cannot find out how to use $AA^t=\alpha I$ further.

**EDIT:** Well, I have found a way to proceed further:

Let $\lambda$ be a non-zero eigen value of $A^tA$. Then it can be proved it is also an eigen value of $AA^t$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087064/non-zero-eigenvalues-of-aat-and-ata)). Therefore, there exits a non-zero vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^m$ such that $AA^tv=\lambda v$. Again from the **given equation** we have, $v^tAA^tv=\alpha v^tv$, i.e., $v^t(AA^tv)=\alpha v^tv$, or, $\lambda v^tv=\alpha v^tv$ this implies, $\lambda = \alpha$.

Hence the only non-zero eigen value of $A^tA$ is $\alpha$.

So, finally Correct options are $1,2$ and $3$.

Please tell me whether I am right or made any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic looks good to me, though it can be done more simply than you have it. You were on the right track with setting $x = Av$. Then
$$A^tx = A^tAv = \lambda v\\AA^tx = \lambda Av = \lambda x\\x^tAA^tx = \lambda x^tx\\\alpha x^tx = \lambda x^tx$$
Since $\|x\| \ne 0$, we have $\lambda = \alpha$.